# How do I make my API action accept null complex types?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

So this works perfect

```
//localhost:1234/api/task/getData?id=1&name=test&phone=123456

public object GetData(long id, [FromUri] User complexType)
{
    //complexType is binding correctly
    return runSomeCode(id, complexType ?? User.Current);
}
```

But this doesn't. Not sure how to specify a null complex type.

```
//localhost:1234/api/task/getData?id=1

public object GetData(long id, [FromUri] User complexType)
{
    //complexType is not null, but all class properties are
    return runSomeCode(id, complexType ?? User.Current);
}
```

I even tried this but ran into new problems with "Multiple actions were found that match the request"

```
//localhost:1234/api/task/getData?id=1

public object GetData(long id)
{
    return runSomeCode(id, User.Current);
}

public object GetData(long id, [FromUri] User complexType)
{
    return runSomeCode(id, complexType);
}
```

Here is what my complex class looks like

```
public class User
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Phone {get;set;}

    public static User Current
    {
        get
        {
            //code to get the current user
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
I know that changing my method to a POST and using the body content works, but lets say that I'm stubborn and wish to accomplish this using GET.

How do I make a complex parameter nullable in an web api GET request? Excluding it doesn't work like in a POST request.

Comment: how this user type looks lke

Comment: It's a simple class. I'll update the question.

Comment: What does `But this doesn't` mean? How does it not work. Is the method never executed, is there an exception inside the method?

Comment: @ErikPhilips - I expected the User parameter to be null if nothing is specified in the Uri. This isn't the case, so I have a lack of understanding how parameter binding works. If nothing is specified in the Uri, web api still creates an instance of the class, but with null values for all of it's properties. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Dalorzo - See my first example. Complex type works with a GET request.

Comment: I just understood what you mean, apologies for the misunderstanding

Comment: This is the default model binding behavior. An instance of the type is created, and the default model binder attempts to bind HTTP values (in this case) to model values on the User object. Since the route matches, I think you'd have to supply your own model binder that somehow returns null if no properties were actually bound - or make sure the route *doesn't* match, which case you action method won't be called at all.

Comment: [Dalorzo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23371304/7724) contains the solution, but it's hidden in the wall of text. In your case, making a simple Type Converter like the `[TypeConverter(typeof(GeoPointConverter))]` in the example on [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) to convert your complex type into `null` if values are missing will work.

Comment: @bzlm - Thanks for the update. I came across the TypeConverter already and wanted to know if this was the only way. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you are looking for is how to define "Routing Rules"

**WebApi 2.0** let's use an attribute called `Route` to define different "Resource URLs" with some rules(constraints) like length, format and default values

For example:

```
public class SomeController : ApiController{
     //where author is a letter(a-Z) with a minimum of 5 character and 10 max.      
    [Route("html/{id}/{newAuthor:alpha:length(5,10)}/age:int?")]
    public Book Get(int id, string newAuthor , int age){
        return new Book() { Title = "SQL Server 2012 id= " + id, Author = "Adrian & " + newAuthor };
    }
```

Where the parameter **age** is of type `integer` and ***optional***.

Or like this using a default value:

```
[Route("html/{id}/{newAuthor:alpha:length(5,10)}/age:int=33")]
public Book Get(int id, string newAuthor , int age){
  return new Book() { Title = "SQL Server 2012 id= " + id, Author = "Adrian & " + newAuthor };
}
    ...
```

Or being able to customize your routings based on your needs like :

```
[Route("url1/{id}")]
public Book Get(int id){
   return new Book() { Title = "SQL Server 2012 id= " + id, Author = "Adrian " };
}

[Route("url1/{id}/{author}")]
public Book Get(int id, string author){
   return new Book() { Title = "SQL Server 2012 id= " + id, Author = "Adrian & " + author };
}
...
```

In the first version of the WebApi this had to be done in the `WebApiConfig` class however the options are not the same, I think the only real option on that version was the use of regular expressions.

Going back to Web.Api 20 you also can define your own constraints to handle your own complex types by inheriting from `IHttpRouteConstraint`

There is additional information regarding the scenario you described on the WEB.Api documentation site, it is possible that you may need to implement a `TypeConverter`.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: Are you sure this is what the OP is asking or? If your constraint isn't fulfilled, this won't match the route, but I think the OP wants the route to match but the User model-bound to null instead of an instance of User.

Comment: @bzlm can you tell me why Routing rules won't work? I just read your comments and I am even more convinced it is about routing rules

Comment: See the second code example in the question. In this case, the OP *wants* the route to match, but the from-URI-bound argument to be null. If you add constraints on properties of the from-URI-bound argument, such as "Name must be specified", then the route *won't* match and the action method won't be invoked. Right?

Comment: It will if you implement either your own TypeConverter or IHttpRouteConstraint

Comment: @bzlm you can refer to this URL on how to implement your own constraints http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: Using a custom Type Converter will work, as will using a custom Model Binder (which can do type conversion *and* other things). But I fail to see how route constraints will solve the second code example in the question. Route constraints return true or false, they don't meddle with model binding. Perhaps you are referring to using route default values somehow?